# picture / geometrical interpretation of mapping cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-interpretation

Can someone give me a geometrical interpretation (picture) of mapping cylinder of a continuous map $g: X \to Y$, where $\operatorname{Cyl}(g) = Z \cup_f Y$, where $Z = X  \times [0, 1],\,
A = X \times \{0\}$ and $f$ is $g$ composed with the obvious identification $X \times \{0\} \cong X$.

Or its mapping cone, where $\operatorname{Cone}(g) = \operatorname{Cyl}(g)/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation such that $(x, 1) \sim (x', 1)$ for all $x, x' \in X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [graduation cap](http://cliparting.com/free-graduation-clip-art-4707/) is an example of a mapping cylinder $g : X \to Y$ where $X = S^1$, $Y = [-2,2] \times [-2,2]$, and $g$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: And do you might know what would be its mapping cone? (under these assumptions)

Comment: And sorry for bothering, but what would be f in our upper case for mapping cylinder?

Comment: $f$ is the map from $S^1$ to the bottom edge of the graduation cap.

Comment: The mapping cone in this example is obtained by taking the bottom edge of the graduation cap and shrinking it to a point. Thus the vertical part of the graduation cap, instead of looking like a cylinder (hence the term "mapping cylinder") will look like a cone (hence the term "mapping cone").